# Different ng-pattern Behaviors

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs, ng-pattern

**Scenario**

I'm using `ng-pattern` in a project where I need to dynamically generate regular expressions via string concatenation meaning the end result is `var regexp = "regexp"` rather than `var regexp = /regexp/`.

**The Problem**

I know that this code works:

```
//JavaScript
$scope.regex = /[^0-9\|]+/;

//HTML
<input type="text" name="first" ng-model="a" ng-pattern="regex">
```

But I need to be able to use a string like so:

```
//JavaScript
$scope.regex = "[^0-9\|]+";

//HTML
<input type="text" name="first" ng-model="a" ng-pattern="{{regex}}">
```

**The Question**

How can I use my dynamically generated string regular expression with `ng-pattern`?

**Plunker**

I've prepped a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/alebX5n4Be4Atqqb1OLI?p=preview) demonstrating three different uses of `ng-pattern` in which only the literal regular expression works. I'd be so grateful for any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do var c = /string/; You're creating a regex literal. This is not the only way to create a regex in JS. Like you can create objects by other means than object literals. RegExp takes in a string and returns a regex literal using that string as the pattern.

```
$scope.regex = new RegExp(string)
```

So if I wanted to create a regex dynamically using concated strings. It would look like something like this.

```
var something = "a";
something += "|b"
$scope.regex = new RegExp(something);
// $scope.regex == /a|b/
```